# How to su to a daemon user?

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, services, su, mongodb

To repair mongodb running on arch linux arm, the doc says that the specific command must be run with the same user as the one running the service, to avoid permission issues later on.

The dbpath folder belongs to the `mongodb` user, so I guess it's the user running the service. How can I find the password to `su` it to issue the repair command? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service accounts are typically locked, i.e. there is no password that you can login with. If you are the administrator of the system, then become root by way of `su` or `sudo`, and as root issue `su mongodb`.

Comment: Or just `sudo -s -u mongodb` directly.